# Change var onclick button, javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a pause button for this timer. And unfortunately, it's not working.

When id "button-pause" is clicked, I need to set "var pressed = true".

If not, run the script below "if(!pressed){" and let "var pressed = false".

What's wrong?

HTML

```
<span id="button-pause">
  <span class="music"></span>
  <img src='img/icons/pause.png' alt='Stop music'>
</span>
```

JavaScript

```
var minutes = 60;

// Set number of seconds remaining after which to trigger a warning color
var warning = 59;
var pressed = false;
k = document.getElementById('button-pause');

k.onclick = function () {
  pressed = true;
}

if(!pressed){
  // Declare variables
  var timerEl, seconds, timer;

  // Get a reference to the HTML element
  timerEl = document.getElementById('tim');

  // Calculate total seconds
  seconds = 1*minutes;

  // Updates the timer element
  function updateTimer() {
    var m,s;

    // Get whole minutes
    m = Math.floor(seconds/60);

    // Get left-over seconds
    s = seconds % 60;

    // Pad anything below 10 with a leading zero
    s = (s < 10) ? "0"+s : s;

    // Write time to HTML element
    timerEl.innerHTML = m + ":" + s;

    // Decrement seconds
    seconds--;

    // Add warning class when we hit threshold
    if(seconds < warning) {
      timerEl.classList.add('warning');
    }
    // Clear timer when we hit zero
    if(seconds < 0) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      window.location.href='index.php?mode=workout&workoutid=test&status=done';
    }
  }
}

timer = setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Well, set the var pressed = true when id "button-pause" clicked

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is using the same variable for two things

```
var pressed = false;  <-- store a boolean
pressed = document.getElementById('button-pause');  <--override the boolean  with the button
```

Second issue is the JavaScript code is not going to change when you click the button. It will set the variable, but the code that has already run will not update magically. You would need to add the code to some sort of function and trigger it when the button is clicked or when the page is loaded.

Comment: Thank you, I noticed it too after I posted it, but anyway , thank you.

About the chaning code while running - any possibility how to do that?